# Solutions to functional equation $f(f(x))=x$

Tags: functional-equations

Is there any more solutions to this functional equation $f(f(x))=x$?

I have found: $f(x)=C-x$ and $f(x)=\frac{C}{x}$.

Comment: It likely matters what assumptions of continuity you make. But beyond that I think those are be the only ones.

Comment: If these are the only continuous ones, interesting to see what discontinuous solutions are like.

Comment: $f(x) = x$ is also a "nice" solution.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Oops, missed the simplest one)

Comment: And there is a good case against $\frac{C}{x}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas you mean division by zero? That's only one point)

Comment: One thing I notice is that all of the nice cases (accepting $1/x$ for the moment) are all Mobius transforms which happen to be their own inverse.

Comment: functional square root: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_square_root

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you don't make any niceness assumptions about $f$, there are lots. Partition $\Bbb{R}$ (or whatever you want $f$'s domain to be) into $1$- and $2$-element subsets, in any way you like. Then define $f(x)=y$, if $\{x, y\}$ is in your partition, or $f(x)=x$, if $\{x\}$ is in your partition.

Moreover, any such $f$ yields such a partition, into the sets $\{x, f(x)\}$. So this is a complete description of all solutions.

Of course, $f$ will be wildly discontinuous for most choices of partition.

Answer (score 3):

This answer will only deal with continuous maps.

---

A map $f : X \to X$ such that $f \circ f = \operatorname{id}_X$ is called an *involution* of $X$. Two involutions of $X$, $f$ and $g$, are said to be *equivalent* if there is a self-homeomorphism $h$ such that $f\circ h = h\circ g$ (or written differently, $f = h\circ g \circ h^{-1}$). With this terminology at our disposal, we can state the following result.

> Every non-identity involution of $\mathbb{R}$ is equivalent to the involution $g(x) = -x$.

Therefore, $f$ is an involution of $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if $f = h\circ g\circ h^{-1}$ for some homeomorphism $h : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, or $f = \operatorname{id}_X$.

For example, if we let $f(x) = C - x$, then $f = h\circ g\circ h^{-1}$ where $h : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is the homeomorphism given by $h(x) = x + \frac{C}{2}$.

Comment: How do you prove that result?

Answer (score 2):

$f(x) = c-x$

$f(x) = c/x$

$f(x) = \frac{c_{1}-x}{c_{2}x+1}$

$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left ( \sqrt[]{{c_{1}^2}+c_{2}-4x^2} \right )+ c_{1}x$

$f(x) = \sqrt[3]{c-x^3}$

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28f%28x%29%29%3Dx

Comment: The last one can be generalized (will include first one): $f(x)=\sqrt[a]{b-x^a}$

Comment: @user2992539 Only works if $a$ is an odd integer.

Comment: Why $f(x)=x$ is not in the answers?

Answer (score 1):

Any function whose graphic is symmetric against the line y=x.

Comment: And therefore the implicit form of the function should be invariant when swapping coordinates, $F(x,y)=F(y,x)=0$. The examples in the question are the simplest possible choices $F_1(x,y) = x+y-C=0$ and $F_2(x,y) = x\cdot y-C=0$

Comment: -1: flippant, incomplete.  Your answer does not show that the class with this symmetry has any members other than those in the question

Answer (score -1):

In fact this belongs to a functional equation of the form http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/fe/fe2315.pdf.

Let $\begin{cases}x=u(t)\\f=u(t+1)\end{cases}$ ,

Then $u(t+2)=u(t)$

$u(t)=\theta(t)$ , where $\theta(t)$ is an arbitrary periodic functions with period $2$

$\therefore\begin{cases}x=\theta(t)\\f=\theta(t+1)\end{cases}$ , where $\theta(t)$ is an arbitrary periodic functions with period $2$